# Converting one column into multiple columns and counts of each category in PostgreSQL (R dcast Python Pivot_Table)?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

MY Structure looks like

```
Y    | M     | P 
2018 |  8    |  A
2018 |  8    |  A
2018 |  9    |  A
2018 |  9    |  B
```

I am seeking to achieve

```
Y    | M    |  A  | B
2018 |  8   |  2  | 0
2018 |  9   |  1  | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for that:

```
select y,m,
       count(*) filter (where p = 'A') as a,
       count(*) filter (where p = 'B') as b
from the_table
group by y,m
order by y,m
```